# Another Fragment on top op a Mapview (SupportMapFragment)

Tags: java, android-layout, android-fragments, android-mapview, supportmapfragment

Im adding another Fragment to the screen. This screen already has en MapView in a SupportMapFragment so the added Fragment should be on top of the MapView. This new view cover like 2/3 of the screen and a big part of the Map but when I scroll on the View it scrolls the MapView underneath. This is not what i expected because the new View is added on top of the MapView. The new view exist of a relative layout containing a ImageView which wraps it contents. So when scrolling on the imageview (which has totally no functionality) it scrolls the MapView. Can anyone explain why this happens and if possible, provide me with a solution?

EDIT:

basically i have a MapView which fills the whole screen. This code sets up my mapview:

```
public void setUpMapIfNeeded(int satelliteMode, LatLng startPoint, float zoomLevel) {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mapView == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mapView = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapview))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mapView != null) {
                setUpMap(satelliteMode, startPoint, zoomLevel);
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap(int satelliteMode, LatLng startPoint, float zoomLevel) {
        // more settings
        }
```

Then when a user clicks a marker a fragment must be shown on top of the mapview.

```
public void createDetailView() {
        detailView = new DetailViewFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.viewLayout, detailView).commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
    }
```

This all works fine. The view is shown (which is about 2/3 of the whole screen) but user can scroll the map when swiping the detailview. The detailview consist of a relative layout with a lot of text and buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="45sp">


<!-- a lot of text and buttons here -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No solution?.. We just accept that the map can be touched even when its below another fragment?

Comment: Can you please provide some code related to the situation you're facing? How you have coded the action listeners for touch events on those different views? One possible problem may be on touch event listeners, if the program can't distinguish to which layer of the screen the tap / swipe events belong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I still havent found a proper way to deal with this. Instead I just disabled all touches and clicks on the mapview when another view is on top of the mapview which btw works ok.

Comment: I'm facing same of your problem too. I have mapview and i want to use fragment top of mapview when i scroll on the fragment it scrolls map too. But i have button inside the fragment ? how could you solve this situation ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it might still be relevant, the way I've handled this kinds of layouts (one view appearing "on top of" another) is to use `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout` in the following way:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <SomeView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <PopOutView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your case the map would be that `SomeView` and the relative layout the `PopOutView`. Then in the code you would just call `popOutView.setVisibility = View.VISIBLE` whenever you would like it to show up. It shrinks the first view instead of being drawn on top (thus having a bit different visual effect) but at least this way the touch events should go to the right view.

Answer (score 0):

Set the fragment's layout clickable property to true. It will stop the touch events from propagating down.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:clickable="true">
</FrameLayout>
```